# android table column sizing

Tags: android, forms, layout

I want to achieve a layout where screen is divided vertically in half, right half has 1 text field and left side has text and edit field. I want left text fiels to start from center and left side fields end at center. I tried to use below code but it does not work.

I used linear layout, how can i move the text box to left of center in below code

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/calcInterestRateRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:text="%" android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/calcInterestRateLabel"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="90dip"
                android:lines="1" android:inputType="phone" android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/calcSalesTaxLabel"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Interest Rate %"
            android:textColor="@color/white" android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/interest_rate_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="%"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/interest_rate_edit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Interest Rate..."
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sales_tax_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Interest Rate %"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

I'll test it when I get home, I think that will work though. Basically, just put two separate LinearLayouts within a LinearLayout, each weighted to 1 (so they are of equal width), then place your views within these LinearLayouts. You may also want to add some padding to the LinearLayouts as well.

EDIT: Try this way with a TableLayout. It's not perfect, but it'll get you there!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1|2"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:hint="percent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Interest Rate"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:hint="months"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Loan Term"
            />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: That looks like a TableLayout might work better for you. I'm not too confident in my TableLayout lingo, so I'll wait to try an example of that till I get home. You'd basically want a two-column table layout of equal width, with the left column having gravity="right", and the right column having gravity="left".

Comment: Added a TableLayout solution!

Comment: Thank You for the code it helps understand table layout. For the layout I am trying to achieve 2nd row editText has smaller width and if I set it manually say '25dip' rather then using 'wrap_content' it does not work.